# How to read instream data

Tags: sas

I know that this is a very basic question, but I really am having trouble.

I wrote the following code and all I want to do is to read the data correctly, but I cannot find a way to instruct SAS to read the BMI.

There are two things I want to do.

1), Have SAS store the entire number including all the decimals.
2), when printed, I would like to approximate the number to two decimal points.

```
data HW02EX01;
  input Patient 1-2  Weight 5-7 Height 9-10 Age 13-14 BMI 17-26 Smoking $ 29-40 Asthma $ 45-48;
  cards;
14  167 70  65  23.9593878  never           no
run;
```

Note: I left only the first observation since the display becomes really ugly and wearisome to edit by hand.

Comment: I don't understand your first question. Your current code should read BMI fine for the line you posted. If the other lines have BMI value in the same columns they will work also.

Comment: Regarding the questions, if you indent your code 4 spaces (a tab) or click the `{}` icon it will format the code for you to make it legible and cleaner. You see the text below your post to ensure it's correct. You can also visit [ask] to see recommendations on posting a good question.

Answer (score 2):

friend.

Maybe it could be useful the following code:

```
data HW02EX01_;
    input Patient Weight Height Age BMI Smoking : $20. Asthma $10.;
    format BMI 32.2;
    cards;
14 167 70 65 23.9593878 never no
;
```

By way of comment, I would like to indicate some details:

- If your input data has a fixed length, use the column reading method as you propose in your code in the input statement. If not, use a list reading entry (assuming there is a delimiter between your input data).
- When SAS reads in the list form, it converts and saves all the digits of a numerical value. So you do not have to worry about reading decimals too.
- To display a numerical value the way you like it, you can use the format statement to assign a representation of the value. In this case with two decimals we use the format "w.d". Where w is the total length of the number that can occur and d indicates the number of decimals to show. It should be mentioned that the formats do not change the value of the variable, only its presentation.
- When using the cards statement, it is not necessary to use a run statement.

I hope it will be useful.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you.  I still have some questions, though.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you.  I still have some questions, though.

1), I am a beginner and am not familiar with your use of the colon where you coded
Smoking : $20

2), Why did you specify the length to be 20?

3), Why did you specify the w.d for BMI as 32.2?

4),  I would like to be able to write my questions like the way it is after it was edited by a kind person.  I would like to know how it was done, so if you could kindly guide me to where I can learn this procedure I would be very glad.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments in the code, specifically the usage of `LENGTH`, `FORMAT` and `INFORMAT` statements to control the input and output appearance of data.

```
data HW02EX01;
    *specify the length of the variables;
    length patient $8. weight height age bmi 8. smoking asthma $8.; 


    *specify the informats of the variables; 
    *an informat is does the variable look like when trying to read it in;
    informat patient $8. weight height age bmi best32.;

    *formats control how infomraiton is displayed in output/tables;
    format bmi 32.2 weight height age 12.;

    input Patient $ Weight Height Age BMI Smoking  Asthma ;
    cards;
14 167 70 65 23.9593878 never no
;

run;
```